# A question about disabling intel me

Tags: intel

On System76 laptops is possible to disable this unsafe thing called IME (not on all models as I understand).
The procedure is described [here](https://github.com/system76/firmware-open/blob/master/docs/intel-me.md)

I have ordered from another site a laptop, with dasharo coreboot firmware and i7-1260P cpu.
I can follow the same procedure for system76 firmware or I risk to broke something?

Comment: There is nothing wrong that I know of to have Intel Management Engine installed. I have it on all my laptops.  Ask the computer manufacturer Support. They should provide up to date drivers if they have the engine installed

Comment: @John the Intel Management Engine was found to have [several critical flaws](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Intel+Management+engine+CVE) many years ago that meant a system could potentially be compromised locally or remotely and at levels that would make it impossible for a normal user to detect or defend against. The Management Engine has full authority over the CPU and memory and so could be used to create a persistent rootkit that could never be removed as it was part of the system management engine platform. Some manufacturers made machines with it disabled as a result.

Comment: Interesting. I never had an issue with it. But that is why I suggested contacting Support either to get a good driver or else to properly disable it.  I think the flaws have been addressed by now also

Comment: @John You don't **know** if you ever had an issue with that. There are critical flaws in the design of the system, which cannot simply be addressed. [Checkout this talk for in-depth information about the system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CQUNd3oKBM&t=13s)

Comment: These flaws were identified 4 to 5 years ago. New computers from good manufacturers have good hardware and drivers to secure them. So that is what I am thinking.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that a manufacturer like Lenovo will not keep a design from 5 years ago and keep the hardware deficiency alive

Comment: The flaws were identified 5 years ago, but the os which the intel me is same (minix) and i don't know if is patched..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the procedure described for system76 laptops and...

```
./coreboot/util/nvramtool/nvramtool -w me_state=Disable
nvramtool: CMOS option table not found in coreboot table.  Apparently, the coreboot installed on this system was built without selecting CONFIG_USE_OPTION_TABLE.
```

:(

I have write an email to my laptop vendor and he said currently is not possible to disable the IME, but they are discuss about it with the firmware developer to get support for our devices.
So..there is an hope for the future.

EDIT: The future is come
With the latest firmware 1.6.0 is possible do disable the IME direct from bios interface.
For more info go here

[firmware release for Dasharo](https://docs.dasharo.com/variants/novacustom_ns5x_adl/releases/#v160-2023-04-07)

[how to update](https://docs.dasharo.com/unified/novacustom/firmware-update/)

[image]